# Copy favourites on Chrome between my laptop and PC?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

How do I copy all my favourites (Chrome) from my laptop to my other PC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use Google Sync already built into Chrome? You simply supply your username and password for you google account and Chrome does the rest. It has the added advantages of also syncing your extensions, themes and preferences. It also has the added advantage of keeping everything in sync all the time, so if you change something on the one, well, the other changes too.

- Click the Spanner
- Click Preferences
- Click Personal Stuff
- Click Setup Sync

Once done it will look as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a google account, see [How To Sync Chrome Bookmarks Using Your Google Account](http://www.guidingtech.com/3125/chrome-bookmarks-sync/).

Otherwise, see if this helps:
[Google Chrome: Sync, Backup, Export your Bookmarks/Favorites Across Two or more Computers](http://unlockforus.blogspot.com/2008/09/google-chrome-sync-your-bookmarks.html)